# Azure Functions availability on National clouds

Tags: azure-functions

Our services need to deploy to the national clouds. Are Azure Functions available on National clouds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Azure Functions is available in all national clouds on dedicated (app service) plans. ([blog announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/03/28/announcing-the-availability-of-azure-functions-in-national-clouds/)) The consumption plan for Functions will be available in November 2018 for Microsoft Cloud for US Government only.